# What does 黒瞳 means?

Tags: translation, words

I've came across this kanji when reading this fantasy light novel, **黒【こく】瞳【どう】** (the furigana was also in the book), but I can't seem to find the meaning.

I've searched for it in both english and japanese but could not find it.

I know "黒 means black" and "瞳 means pupil", So maybe I'm supposed to think that this means "black pupil"?! But google image only shows black pupils/eyes if I type 黒い瞳.

For context, the following line contains that word in the book (where a girl's appearence is being described):

> 背中にかかるほど長い髪も、露出の少ない肌も目を奪われるほど白く、細い肢体を包む喪服のような漆黒のドレスと、高い知性を窺わせる**黒【こく】瞳【どう】**だけが、幻のように儚げな少女の実在を証明している。

From that whole line, the only thing I can't understand is 「高い知性を窺わせる黒瞳」... **Black eyes that make you presume she's super intelligent**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who owns a huge dictionary may find an entry for it, but perhaps a more important fact is that most Japanese speakers (including myself) do not recognize it as a standalone word. I am aware of no reason why having black pupils can suggest high intelligence. A quick google search gave nothing, either. The basic meaning ("black eyes") is self-explanatory, and I think most native speakers will read on without even wondering.

Comment: Yes, I revised the latter kanji many times to make sure I was typing the correct one. I guess the author wants to be "fancy" with his words. The intelligence part is indeed weird though. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I think the author is just talking about 知性を窺わせる瞳 that *happen to be black*, not 知性を窺わせる瞳 because of its blackness.

Comment: I would probably translate that as something like "Black eyes that glimmer with intelligence." It doesn't make sense literally but it is more of a way to just state the fact that she has black eyes and also is intelligent.

Comment: @firedraco ohh, that's a good way to translate it, and it goes well with naruto's comment, thank you!!